# Calculating Mean And Standard Deviation With Data That Meets A Condition

Tags: pine-script

I have an indicator that oscillates between 1 and -1 based on the value of a single variable, let's call it M. I would like to take the mean and sDev of M over a length of time, but I want to do that separately for the positive values and negative values of M.

In other words, I want to be able to get the mean of M when M > 0 over a time series while ignoring any values when M < 0 in the time series. Likewise for the sDev, and vise versa for the negative values.

I am not sure how to filter out the data I don't want in the code or if this is possible. Thanks for the help!

**Update**

It seems that I ran into another problem that might be a separate question, but I will provide some context here. What I wanted to do is take the standard deviation and add it to the mean for a given look back period, and do that separately for the positive and negative sides of the indicator.

What I found was that taking the moving average worked as expected. When the oscillator flipped to pos to neg or the other way, the mean calculation simply started back up again for a given side using values from the last time it was pos or neg. Screens below to illustrate all these points.

The stdev() function was another matter. It did not act like the sma() function counting each side. Instead, it would only count the sdev of the series when the look back period was greater than or equal to an unbroken sequence of pos or neg values. so if I set my look back period to 60, which is long, there was never a time series that all pos or neg for that length so the sdev would read as na. I had hoped it would just incorporate the sdev of the earlier parts of the series, but that does not seems to be the case. Here are said screens and code to help illustrate

```
Upper = Spread > 0 ? Spread : na
Lower = Spread < 0 ? Spread : na

lbp = 60  //avg and sdev look back periods
sDevLbp = 7  

UpperSdev = stdev(Upper,sDevLbp)
LowerSdev = stdev(Lower,sDevLbp)


UpperTreshold = sma(Upper,lbp)
LowerTreshold = sma(Lower,lbp)


plot(msaSpread, title='MSA Spread', style=columns)
plot(UpperS, title='Upper S', style=line, color=orange)
plot(UpperTreshold, title='Upper Band', style=line, color=purple)
```

This first screenshot of the output shows me highlighting an early bar in an impulse up. Not that in the Data window the sdev is na and the mean is not.

[Image1 Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjAeR.png)

In the second one, I highlight a bar that is equal to or greater than the sdev look back period (seven in this case) in the same impulse on the positive side. Not the upper sdev shows a value.

[Image 2 Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5NJK.png)

The issue now is that because of the way the stdev() function is acting, I can't calculate a longer term sdev. I haven't been able to find a work around to get to the earlier entries in the series. I am just reading that new answer now, so I'll give that a shot.

**Update 2**

I got things working 95% using the kind advice of [Gustavo Cardelle](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5577188/gustavo-cardelle) below. I have one tiny issue that I haven't sorted yet, but I'll get to that in a bit. What I did was look back over a long range and built the avg and sDev using a fixed number of good values. So if the look back period I want is the avg and sDev over 15 non-na bars, I'll look back over 100 bars and grab the most recent 15 good ones and compute with those. Code and screens below. The issue I have is that while the upper bound looks right, that is it moves when the values are positive and is flat when the values are negative, the lower bound seems to wiggle while the values are positive. I am not sure why this is.

```
lbp = 15
Range = 100

lbpCount = 1
UpperAVG = 0.0
for i = 0 to Range+1
    if(na(Upper[i]))
        continue
    if(lbpCount<=lbp)
        UpperAVG := UpperAVG+Upper[i]
        lbpCount := lbpCount+1
    if(lbpCount>lbp)
        UpperAVG := UpperAVG/lbp
        break

lbpCount2 = 1
holder = 0.0
UpperSTDEV = 0.0
for i = 0 to Range+1
    if(na(Upper[i]))
        continue
    if(lbpCount2<=lbp)
        holder := Upper[i] - UpperAVG
        holder := holder*holder
        UpperSTDEV := UpperSTDEV + holder
        lbpCount2 := lbpCount2+1
    if(lbpCount2>lbp)
        UpperSTDEV := UpperSTDEV/lbp
        UpperSTDEV := sqrt(UpperSTDEV)
        break

plot(UpperSTDEV+UpperAVG, title='UpperBOUND', color=orange )        


lbpCount3 = 1
LowerAVG = 0.0
for i = 0 to Range+1
    if(na(Lower[i]))
        continue
    if(lbpCount3<=lbp)
        LowerAVG := LowerAVG+Lower[i]
        lbpCount3 := lbpCount3+1
    if(lbpCount3>lbp)
        LowerAVG := LowerAVG/lbp
        break

lbpCount4 = 1
holder4 = 0.0
LowerSTDEV = 0.0
for i = 0 to Range+1
    if(na(Lower[i]))
        continue
    if(lbpCount4<=lbp)
        holder4 := Lower[i] - LowerAVG
        holder4 := holder4*holder4
        LowerSTDEV := LowerSTDEV + holder4
        lbpCount4 := lbpCount4+1
    if(lbpCount4>lbp)
        LowerSTDEV := LowerSTDEV/lbp
        LowerSTDEV := sqrt(LowerSTDEV)
        break

plot(LowerAVG-LowerSTDEV, title='LowerBOUND', color=orange )
```

here is a pic of the output:

[Output Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8BV65.png)

So as you can see, the lower bound is a bit odd, as it moves even when the values aren't negative (hence nothing is changing). I thought it had something to do with the negative values in the sdev calculation, but I think my math is right. I may have been staring at this too long, or it might be right and I don't get why. There you have it! Just need to work out the last detail. Thanks for all you help!

**Update 3**

figured the last bit out and updated the code above. Works as intended!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is running against some limitations.

Let's first discuss why `sma()` does it well while `stdev()` doesn't: when you're calculating an average and a value is missing, you just replace the missing value by the last known average and your average calculation does not suffer from that. However, the standard deviation is non-linearly dependent on the amount of samples and guessing which value to use to replace the na's so that the final result doesn't change is a heavy iterative process for what pine is *NOT* (edit) meant to.

That said, and considering the biased standard deviation expression as in:

[image: Biased standard deviation]

I would suggest the following work-around:

1) make a `for` loop where you look N bars back in time and compute the average of the values you're interested in (either only positive or only negative). Take the chance to compute N, that is, the amount of valid values you're averaging

2) make another `for` loop where you look again the same N bars back in time and compute the squared difference summation of each valid data point compared to the average value calculated in step one. This is the SIGMA[(xi-x_avg)^2] part of the formula)

3) divide the result of of step 2 by N obtained in step 1

4) obtain the desired stdev by square-rooting the value obtained in step 3

At the end, the task is difficult because Pine does not allow us to play with variable sized vectors, and because of the very nature of the standard deviation function.

Comment: Thanks! will work on this angle and report back. Makes a lot of sense :)

Comment: I think I have it nearly working! thanks so much for your advice. You can check the update to see where I am at.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a *Ternary conditional operator* and create two variables (positive and negative)

Something like that

```
ema_M = ema(M, length)
ema_M_Pos = M > 0 ? ema_M : na
ema_M_Neg = M < 0 ? ema_M : na
plot (ema_M_Pos)
plot (ema_M_Neg)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this a shot this evening and let you know how it goes.

Comment: I'll have to write this up later because its definitely gotten complicated. Suffice to say, sma() seems to do fine, but stdev() behaves in an unexpected way and I haven't figured out how to get around it yet. Will keep digging.

Comment: ok, here is a brief explanation, as I'll be amending the question above with screen shot and more details. I still can't do what I want because it appears that the stdev function behaves not as I expected when using Ternary conditionals. If you set a long look back period of say 30 or 40, it simply won't work. It will output as na unless there is an uninterrupted set of reading from the inidcator that are on one side or the other. the sma funciton does not seem to do this and works as I expected.